# Error message when trying to load second activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm very new to Android development, and I'm following the development guide as close as I can, but I seem to have hit a snag.

I have a simple main activity with a text edit and an image button. 
When the image button is clicked, the text from the text edit element should be displayed in a second activity.

But when the button is clicked...!

I've been trying to use LogCat to diagnose the issue as many other people have suggested but my understanding is too limited to find the relevant issue!

This is what it comes up with in logCat when I click the button ...

> 06-12 19:01:11.830: E/AndroidRuntime(853): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.azura_apps.pylon/com.azura_apps.pylon.BeginHoax}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c
>   (com.azura_apps.pylon:id/container) for fragment
>   PlaceholderFragment{b2d445c0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}

As i have come to understand it, there could be an issue with adding the activity to the manifest correctly, but I fail to see an issue.

This is my manifest -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.azura_apps.pylon"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.azura_apps.pylon.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.azura_apps.pylon.BeginHoax"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_begin_hoax" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I create an intent in my Main Activity with the method name I specified in my layout xml -

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.azura_apps.Pylon.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

public void LoadHoax(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BeginHoax.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.test_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

This is where i retrive the intent in my second activity  - 
public class BeginHoax extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin_hoax);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
}
```

Main Activity Layout XML File -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.azura_apps.pylon.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/welcome_message" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/test_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/enter_test_message" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/test_message"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:onClick="LoadHoax"
        android:src="@drawable/start_scan_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm aware that this question has been answered before, but I'm having trouble applying the answers to my own code!
If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: post the logcat error

Comment: edited to show the logcat error, I think!

Comment: We need more logcat to be sure about the OpenGL error you posted.

Comment: Please remove the screenshots - they're completely unnecessary. Also this part of your second `Activity` ... `MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE` suggests you've created a `public static` field for `EXTRA_MESSAGE` - don't EVER create `public static` fields or methods in an `Activity`. Remove the screenshots, add more of your `Activity` code and more of the logcat.

Comment: @Squonk - updated the question with more activity code. The android guide shows to create a public static field for the extra message. can you explain why this is not the way to go?

Comment: @tinkerbot : Post your `activity_main` XML layout file.

Comment: @tinkerbot : This is your problem. `No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.azura_apps.pylon:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{b2d445c0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}`. It's trying to find a view in your XML layout file with an id of `@+id/container` but your layout file doesn't have it. If you don't want to use the `Fragments` then remove the code in the `onCreate(...)` methods which attempt to add them. The lines which start `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()`

Comment: I've removed the fragments statements. However now it seems that the main activity doesn't display the edit text and image button anymore - simply a blank screen. Please excuse my utter utter ignorance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55538/discussion-between-tinkerbot-and-squonk).

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, since you haven't posted your activity_begin_hoax xml file, but from trying to put the pieces together, this is what I'm getting:

Solution: 
Erase this from your BeginHoax activity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin_hoax);
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
```

Why:
The logcat message is telling you that there is no view with id "container" to put the PlaceholderFragment in.

By default, when you create a new activity in Eclipse, it automatically generates:

a) the activity xml, which is just a fragment container named "container"

b) the fragment xml, where you can put your layout that you want that fragment to make

c) the activity java class file, including an automatic PlaceholderFragment that, by default, builds the fragment xml and puts it in the container view in the activity xml.

If at any point in your testing, you modified the activity_begin_hoax xml file to not include a fragment container with id "container", then that would explain why the app can't find it and crashes.

Since you are not actually using the PlaceholderFragment in your BeginHoax activity (instead setting the content view by making the TextView), erasing the default bits there is an option.

A BETTER option for future real-app making would be to keep the fragment container in your activity xml file, put a textview in your fragment xml file (it probably has one by default anyway), and then inside BeginHoax's fragment you can *get* the textview from the fragment xml file, and put the message in.

```
public class BeginHoax extends ActionBarActivity {

private String message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin_hoax);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new BeginHoaxFragment()).commit();
    }

}

public static class BeginHoaxFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        TextView tv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        tv.setText(message);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: very informative and clear, thanks! I already solved the issue by simply adding the container id to the XML (bit of a bodge, i know), but this is a much better solution! Will try it immediately, Thank you very much sir!